# AngularJS/Ionic - initially loading data into local storage via promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Is there a way to load data into an angular app (maybe right after `app.js` runs) before the rest of the controllers are called? I'm trying to avoid having to load the data as a promise in every controller. I believe asynchronous calls are not supported in the `app.js` .run() or .config() functions and since I'm using Ionic, I don't think I can use angular.bootstrap(). Am I even thinking about this problem correctly? It seems like there's a simple solution I'm missing.

Here's an example of what's being called in many of my controllers now.

**QuestionController.js:**

```
CategoryFactory.getCategories().then(function() { // from JSON file
  StateFactory.setupState(CategoryFactory.categories).then(function () { // from $cordovaNativeStorage
    // initialize scope variables (different for each controller but depend on the user's state and categories loaded)
    $scope.currentCategory = CategoryFactory.categories[StateFactory.getCurrentCategory()];
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use: .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
localStorage.setItem + localStorage.getItem

Comment: Thats a great idea but actually hasn't worked for me because apparently, some of the controllers are running BEFORE the promises with the required data in the $ionicPlatform.ready() function have been returned.

Comment: You can also use $ionicPlatform.ready() inside controllers' code and wait to complete all the sentence. Try it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid though, code in each controller that waits for data to load. If there were a way that would load my data into local storage upon initial load of the app, then each controller could access that data much faster.